# appearance of new page

Tags: pages

I created a new page and can't make it look like all the other pages in my site. New page: http://www.josephflynn.com/uncategorized/fixer-upper/
Old page with proper text/image appearance: http://www.josephflynn.com/donnelys-mug/

Any suggestions? Is the path reference "uncategorized" causing the difference? If so, how do I eliminate it?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.josephflynn.com/uncategorized/fixer-upper/ Is a *Post*.

http://www.josephflynn.com/donnelys-mug/ Is a *Page*.

Your theme has different templates for each. In your case that's Twenty Seventeen, the default theme this year.

Looking at the templates and styling it would be a bit of a pain to change the post template to match the page, so if you're happy with how the Page looks, I'd suggest using Pages for your content like this, rather than Posts. You don't appear to be using a Blog page to show Posts chronologically, so you wouldn't be losing anything doing it that way.

Comment: Identifying the two pages as Post and Page was very helpful and helped me understand the issue. I made a new Page and transferred the text; things are now as I wanted them to be. You mention that my theme is the "default" theme for this year. Do I need to do something to "fix" the theme for more than a specific period of time?

Comment: No sorry, I just mean that WordPress releases a new default theme each year and you’re using the latest. Since you’re already set up it’s not going to change or anything.

Answer (score 1):

The URL: 'http://www.josephflynn.com/uncategorized/fixer-upper/' is a post, not the page, and **uncategorized** is the category for that post. And it looks different because posts load different templates then pages.

You can change the post into the page (create a new page with the same content and remove the post).

Comment: Your response was very helpful. I was able to create a new page with the same content as you suggested. Thank you.